# .toLocaleString() come as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js, embed

So I wrote a code that gets information from https://api.hypixel.net/ which is in JSON,

```
var wolfxpp = response10.data.profile.members[uuis].slayer_bosses.wolf.xp.toLocaleString()
```

If a user doesn't have XP `.toLocaleString` comes as undefined
How can I fix that and make it on embed as '0'

I tried

```
if (response10.data.profile.members[uuis].slayer_bosses.wolf.xp == undefined) {
  return wolfxpp = '0';
}
```

The error stopped showing after this but the embed still haven't been sent
How can I define an undefined value?

Comment: You have a missing ) in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return wolfxpp = '0';`  is not how it works

You could do this

```
 wolfxpp = response10.data.profile.members[uuis].slayer_bosses.wolf.xp;
 if (wolfxpp === undefined) wolfxpp = '0';
```

This is simpler:

```
var wolfxpp = (response10.data.profile.members[uuis].slayer_bosses.wolf.xp || 0).toLocaleString()
```

If there is no xp, use 0 instead. The `(var || 0)` is testing for any falsy value and returns 0 if falsy